# program for calculating metrics in java

Tags: java, metrics

i need to calculate few metrics (CBO, NOC, DAC, LCOM, WMC, RFC and DIT metric). Program is written in jdeveloper and i do not know how to calculate this metrics. Migration to eclipse is not possible becouse code is not compiled. Does anyone know any good program for calculating metrics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most advanced tool in static analyze and report metrics on source code is IMHO
the [Sonar Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/).

Comparatively plain is [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html)

Answer (score 2):

I like [SourceMeter](http://sourcemeter.sourceforge.net/); this [patch](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=37608&atid=420208) shows how to use `JavaCC` for custom Java source code metrics. Some colleagues prefer [cccc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccc/).